# Call MySql Select Query in 2 different php function

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me with my problem.. can i call once Mysql Select Query from different function from two different function too... Sorry i don't know how to explain.. but below my sample what i want to archive..

I want use single query for 2 function.. so maybe i have to write code like below?

```
function sqlSelect ($db, $id, $id2) {
   $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id='$id' AND id2='$id2'");
   $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
   $field = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

   return $row;

}
```

but how to use $field inside 2 diff function?

```
function aaa ($a,$b,$c) {
   if($row >= 1){
      //Do something with $a $b and $c
      //$reget field with $field['column'];
      $field['column']; //???
   }

   return $result;
}

function bbb ($a,$b,$c) {
   if($row >= 1){
      //Do something with $a $b and $c
      //get field with $field['column'];
      $field['column']; //???
   }
}
```

what i do right now is

```
function aaa ($db,$id,$id2,$a,$b,$c) {
   $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id='$id' AND id2='$id2'");
   $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
   $field = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

   if($row >= 1){
      //Do something with $a $b and $c
      //get field with $field['column'];
   }
}

function bbb ($db,$id,$id2,$a,$b,$c) {
   $sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id='$id' AND id2='$id2'");
   $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
   $field = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);

   if($row >= 1){
      //Do something with $a $b and $c
      //get field with $field['column'];
   }
}
```

But if i use what i write and code right now i think it's have to call same query twice. I cannot use query outside function so i have to write query on each function but i want to just write query once and can use in two different function..

Sorry for stupid explanation..

Thank you for help

Comment: so put the query itself into ANOTHER function and have aaa() and bbb() call that function as well.

Comment: isn't same call query twice? same as i do right now?

Comment: and how i get return $field?

Comment: you don't. you return the entire row....

Comment: Maybe i just use array for that.. thanks for response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One implementation can be as follow by passing an array as argument,

```
<?php
$arg['db']="database";
$arg['tabe']="table";
$arg['search']['id1']="id1";
$arg['search']['id2']="id2";
$arg['do_something']['a']="a";
$arg['do_something']['b']="b";
$arg['do_something']['c']="c";
function searchAndDoSomethingAndReturnResult($arg)
{
    $return = NULL;
    $query="SELECT * FROM ".$arg['table'];
    $flag=false;
    foreach($arg['search'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($flag)
            $query.=" AND ";
        else
            $flag=true;
        $query.= $key." = '".$value."' ";
    }
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $field = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
    if($row >= 1)
    {
        foreach($arg['do_something'] as $job=>$value)
        {
            // $return[] = "some result"
            // do something 
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
?>
```

let me know if this solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for answer and remind me that can use array for return.. i just forgot that.. however your answer is great but i can't implemented into my code because will use diff way and place.. But thanks again.. because your answer i just remember to use array.. God Bless You

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass in the `$field` variable as a function argument

```
<?
$field = ...;
function sql1($field,...,...){
    // Use $field here
}
function sql2($field,...,...){
    // Use $field here
}
?>
```

Alternatively, you can use the `global` keyword to access variables from outside of the function

```
<?
$field = ...;
function sql1(){
    global $field;
    // Use $field here
}
function sql2(){
    global $field;
    // Use $field here
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't like use global but thanks anyway for response..God Bless You